# updating nearly place search in google map using dropdown list item

Tags: javascript, google-maps

hello i am doing my first assignment in javascript using gooogle map API.my code is  finding  specific type organizations such as bank or school in near radius, i have already used google map place search library and it gives the result from my given json data. but i have a drop down list one of them is username and other is organization type. My final output will be after clicking a user and a type from dropdownlist ,my map will show the organizations type in user's radius.i saved the dropdown list value in variable  but could not update my map with those. do i need to set initialize method under update method or something kindly help me to sort out this problem. it will be great help

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Place searches</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true&libraries=places"></script>
    <script>
var map;
var infowindow;
var userlist=[
{
  "username":"Tom",
  "Current_latitude":23.752805,
  "Current_longitude":90.375433,
  "radius":500
},

{
  "username":"Jane",
  "Current_latitude":23.752805,
  "Current_longitude":90.375433,
  "radius":400
},

{
  "username":"Dave",
  "Current_latitude": 23.765138,
  "Current_longitude":90.362601,
  "radius":450
},
{
  "username":"Sarah",
  "Current_latitude": 23.792452,
  "Current_longitude":90.416696,
  "radius":600
},

{
  "username":"John",
  "Current_latitude": 23.863064,
  "Current_longitude":90.400126,
  "radius":640
}


];


function update()
{
  var select_name_value=document.getElementById("localperson").value;
  var select_type=document.getElementById("localtype").value;

  if((select_name_value=="tomvalue")&&(select_type=="school"))
  {


     alert("inside update and value are true");




  }
}






function initialize() 
{

  var pyrmont = new google.maps.LatLng(userlist[0].Current_latitude, userlist[0].Current_longitude);

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), 
  {

    center: pyrmont,
    zoom: 15
  });

  var request = 
  {
    location: pyrmont,
    radius:userlist[0].radius ,
    types: ['school']
  };
  infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  service.nearbySearch(request, callback);
}

function callback(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      createMarker(results[i]);
    }
  }
}

function createMarker(place) {
  var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: place.geometry.location
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.setContent(place.name);
    infowindow.open(map, this);
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', update);

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"> </div>

   <label><font size="7" color="green">User</fontsize></label>
    <select id="localperson">
      <option value="" >--Select--</option>
      <option value="tomvalue" >Tom</option>
      <option value="janevalue" >Jane</option>
      <option value="davevalue" >Dave</option>
      <option value="sarahvalue" >Sarah</option>
      <option value="johnvalue" >John</option>
    </select>


  <label><font size="7" color="violet">Type</fontsize></label>
    <select id="localtype">
      <option value="" >--Select--</option>
      <option value="schoolvalue" >School</option>
      <option value="restaurantvalue" >Restaurant</option>
      <option value="bankvalue" >Bank</option>
      <option value="hospitalvalue" >Hospital</option>

    </select>  



  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems in your code.

First, you should do `google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);` rather than update to set up your Maps.

Second, you should call your `update function` when the `<select>`s are `onSelected`, and only do real update if and only if the two selects are selected.

Then, the values in the `<select>` elements do not reflect what you have in your Javascript object, also, you should use an object, using your value as key, rather than using an array. Solution to that might be some stupid operations..

Lastly, in order to update and delete your markers, you need to keep track of them, for example putting them into an array.

Hopes this help.

http://jsfiddle.net/coxb9so4/